# How can I change a log entry in Git?

Tags: git

I commited a new log entry with:

git commit -am "newLogEntry"

Now I want to change the name of my last log entry... (overwriting the last one).

How can I do that? What is the code for that in Git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the name of the last commit, you can write

`git commit --amend -m "New name"`.

You can find more information about `git commit` here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit

Comment: Thanks @ryabv, that's exactly what I wanted.